# How to prevent window-resizing affects your elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okaay, ive been dealing with this problem for quite some time now, and i really need to get an answer now :D The problem is, when im resizing the window, all my elements just messes up. When i try resize other websites(could be anyone; facebook, twitter, even stackoverflow) it does NOT harm any elements. The view just get smaller. How do i do this?

Comment: An example of your markup would go a long way to SO helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

General answer in a general tone:

Conduct some research on responsive web design practice. Learning about different types of layouts (Flexible, full responsive etc.) will certainly help understand the possibilities you have with only CSS and HTML. At least discovering this knowledge will enable you to speak more closely with your developer and head in the right direction.

Cheers!

LaddtheImpaler